# How can I place/drop an image every time you click the mouse button

Tags: html, css

How to make a div appear on click

Comment: Could you please describe your problem a much cleaner, and tell us what you exactly expected to do with a div element?

Comment: I would like help in understanding how I can place an image each time the mouse is clicked. Not sure if a div is needed - so ignore that if it doesn't make sense. similar to the feature on this page   - https://australiahouse.us/ hope this helps.

Comment: Use jquery's toggle function https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using event listeners on mouse click and appending images to the `div` element like below code snippet:

```js
const addImageDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('add-image')[0];
addImageDiv.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const elem = document.createElement("img");
  addImageDiv.appendChild(elem);
  elem.src = 'https://australiahouse.us/sticker-1.png';
        elem.setAttribute('style', `left: ${event.clientX}px; top: ${event.clientY}px; width: 25vw;`);
});
```

```css
.add-image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

body img {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(.35);
}
```

```html
<div class="add-image">
  <span>some content</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
It's a bit trickier to produce a random image of a small set of images, but the best practical way I suggest to create an array of images, then produce a random number and after that get the floor of random number and array length to produce a random index, and at last you can get a random image on each click. (keep in mind in this method, in a small set of images you have to try several times to get a new image on click!)

```js
const addImageDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('add-image')[0];
const imagesArray = ['https://australiahouse.us/sticker-1.png', 'https://australiahouse.us/sticker-2.png', 'https://australiahouse.us/sticker-3.png'];
const imagesArrayLength = imagesArray.length;
addImageDiv.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const randomNumber = Math.random();
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(randomNumber * imagesArrayLength);
  const elem = document.createElement("img");
  addImageDiv.appendChild(elem);
  elem.src = imagesArray[randomIndex];
        elem.setAttribute('style', `left: ${event.clientX}px; top: ${event.clientY}px; width: 25vw;`);
});
```

```css
.add-image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

body img {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(.35);
}
```

```html
<div class="add-image">
  <span>some content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped! do you know how I would get a different image for each click?

Comment: @itskre123 Yes sure, check my edit on the post, and you can get what you needed!